# dropdown form in pure css with a tricky right alignment

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, right-align

I want to make a form only visible if the mouse is hovering an image.

I made a fiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/SoonDead/WScEP/

Here is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: The alignment I'm trying to achieve]

The wrapper has a fixed width, the picture also has a fixed width, but the dropdown has a varying width.

I want to right align the dropdown form, just like the .cart-button picture.

This should not be so difficult but I'm pulling my hair out over this.

Comment: What's currently going wrong? :)

Comment: You might wanna check the answers out... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/WScEP/4/

Comment: Well I don't know... this solution is just as valid as the other one, I'll accept this and upvote the other, but the universe needs to be balanced.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you're after:
http://jsfiddle.net/peduarte/WScEP/6/

I have added comments in the CSS section with what's been added.

Comment: Thanks, pretty understandable with all the comments.